# Rules for exponential and logarithm with complex arguments

Tags: complex-analysis

Stackexchange community,

i have a question concerning the rules for exponentials and logarithms with complex arguments.

For real arguments we have:

$$e^{a+b}=e^a\cdot e^b$$
$$e^{a-b}=e^{a}/e^{b}$$
$$e^{\ln a}=a$$
$$\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln a + \ln b$$
$$\ln(\frac{a}{b})=\ln a - \ln b$$
$$\ln(e^{a})=a$$
$$\log_a(b)=\frac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}$$

Can i use these laws also for complex numbers? I know I have to take care of periodicity and singularities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For exponential, it works the same. For the logarithme it is a little bit different. $$\ln(ab)=\ln(|a||b|)+i\arg(ab)=\ln(|a|)+\ln(|b|)+i\arg(ab)$$

but $$\arg(ab)\equiv \arg(a)+\arg(b)\pmod {2\pi},$$
therefore $$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)\iff \arg(a)+\arg(b)\in]-\pi,\pi[,$$
otherwise $$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)+2ik\pi$$
if $\arg(a)+\arg(b)\in]-\pi+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi[$.

Finally, if you use the property I mentionned before, you will get $$\ln(e^z)=z\iff \Im(z)\in ]-\pi,\pi[.$$

Comment: Your last result is really cool. Does the other way work always? That is, does
$$
z = \exp\ln(z) ?
$$

Comment: Well $$\exp(\ln(z))=e^{\ln(|z|)+i\arg(z)}=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}=z$$ for all $z$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider for instance the first identity, $e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$. To show that this holds for all complex numbers $a$ and $b$ using that you know it holds for real numbers $a$ and $b$, you could argue as follows. Suppose first that $b$ is real, and let $f(z) = e^{z+b}$ and $g(z) = e^ze^b$. These are two holomorphic functions which agree whenever $z$ is real, and therefore by the principle of analytic continuation $f = g$ everywhere. Thus, assuming $b$ is real, $e^{z+b} = e^ze^b$ for all complex numbers $z$. We can now argue like this one more time: now let $a$ be any complex number, and let $f(w) = e^{a+w}$ and $g(w) = e^ae^w$. By the argument just made, we know that $f(w) = g(w)$ whenever $w$ is real, and therefore by analytic continuation $f = g$ everywhere. This proves $e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$ for all complex numbers $a$ and $b$.

Using arguments like these, you can transfer identities you know from the real case to the complex case. As you say, though, when dealing with the logarithms, you really must be very careful to take into account the fact that logarithms are multi-valued functions.

Comment: Nice post. I actually don't understand how one can conclude form f(z) = g(z) for real z that f=g. E.g. let $f(z)=e^{z+Im(z)+b}$ and $g(z)=e^{z+b}$. For $z\in R$ they are the same, but we cant conclude that both functions are the same. Is it because we also assume holomorphic functions? Don't I need these rules to show that both functions are holomorphic?

Comment: Yes, in order to use this argument, you need the principle of analytic continuation, which only applies to holomorphic functions. For the functions like $e^z$ or $e^{z+b}$, this holomorphicity is immediate, since they are defined by convergent power series (on a related note, you could prove the exponent identities directly using the power series expansion).

Comment: Thank you alot for your answer :). You gave me alot of insighs into complex analysis.